# Response comments added to the wrong parent document

Tags: response, parent-child, xpages, repeat

I have a view data source that uses a view key to access documents and show them in a repeat with var "posts". within the repeat I have a document data source with var "post" that gets's the the unid of the documents using posts.getUniversalID().

further down the repeat I have another document data source "newcomment" that is a response and take the parent id as: post.getDocument().getUniversalID()

below the newcomment data source I have an editbox and a submit button which saves the comment as a response to the "post" using newcomment.save()

Here is my problem

two people access the same xpage. personA enters the page and starts writing a comment to a post. in the same time personB creates a new post and submit it before personA submits the comment. What happens now is that the comments gets binded to the latest post and not to the post personA responded to.

I tried anothoher thing also, let's say there is 10 posts in that database. personA and personB access the xpages. personA start writing a comment to post number 8. at the same time personB creates two new posts in the database. when personA now submits the comment it seem to get bind to the same index which is now two posts up. but still index 8. which is ofcourse the wrong post.

If I change the repeat to "createControlsAtPageCreation" ie.e repeatControls=true the comment is attached to the correct post but then I run into another problem that the view is not updated to show the latest posts.

my repeat is wihtin a custom control that is loaded dynamically using the dynamic content control in extlib.

As information here is what I have found about the repeatControls settings

- Setting the repeatControls property to  true instructs the repeat control to create a new copy of its children for each iteration over the dataset.
- When the Repeat control is configured with the property 
  repeatControls=“true” , it repeats its contents only once, at page load time

So my question here is that I do not understand what is going on. why is my comment attached to the wrong parent document? and is there a way I can prevent this and still have new posts displayed correctly

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Without the code it's a bit hard to imagine what exactly is going one here but this looks very similar to problem that I had with repeat control and value binding.

Long story short the problem was connecet to repeatControls property set to false. When it was like that data binding were working only for first element in collection - all data was somehow magically saved to this first object! I managed to get this working by using combination of dynamic content control rebuild and repeatControls set to true. Only then databindings were working property.

It seems like if You are repeating rendering only (and this is what repeatControls set to false do) the decoding phase of jsf lifecycle goes foobar.

Comment: thanks for the info. but doesn't sounds like the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without your XSP markup, it's difficult to be absolutely definitive but it appears that you're  app code is creating and persisting the datasources and components per row during page load - therefore increasing the overall size and complexity of the component tree also.  You should alternatively try an approach that will lazy-load the datasource only when requested by the end-user (eg: edit / reply).

Refer to the XPages Extension Library demo application (XPagesExt.nsf) for examples that use such a dynamic approach.  In particular, look at Core_InPlaceForm.xsp which demonstrates using the xe:inPlaceForm control within a xp:repeat.  And also see Domino_ForumView.xsp which demonstrates using the xe:forumView and xe:forumPost controls to manage and visualize a hierarchical thread.  Also consider the concurrency mode that best suits your requirements when it actually comes to saving any given post or comment (fail, createConflict, force, exception) and document locking for high contention situations.  The above-mentioned controls all provide the highest level of dynamic control and datasource creation and destruction.

Please feel free to send me on a worked example database, where I can understand your exact use case - DM me or email me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony
I did solve the problem with response connected to the wrong parent by disabling partial refresh on the dojo content pane.
The problem I still have is editing a doc in a repeat at index 0 if there is another document created in index 0 that has not yet been displayed using partial refresh.
I already sent Paul H. an email about this